# Trouble in running keyboard module in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keyboard

I downloaded the keyboard module for python, and it runs well on the default python IDLE. But when I try to run it in VS Code, it shows error.
Here's my code:-

```
import keyboard
count = 0
while count <6:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        print(" space is pressed")
        count += 1
```

The error is that:-Module 'keyboard' has no 'is_pressed' member [pylint(no-member)]

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following settings in the settings file "`settings.json`" to avoid such errors:

> `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"],`

In addition, because this kind of error is given by pylint, and this function is provided by the python extension, it is recommended that you use the latest version of the python extension.

Reference: ["settings.json" in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).